# How to solve this? I am having difficulty in the very last step of the problem.

Tags: trigonometry

The general solution of $\vert\sin x\vert = \cos x$ is -

**(A)** $2n\pi+{\pi\over4}$, $n\in I$

**(B)** $2n\pi±{\pi\over4}$, $n\in I$

**(C)** $n\pi+{\pi\over4}$, $n\in I$

**(D)** None of these

So what I did was - I made a case for when sinx is greater than 0 and equated it to $\cos x$ to get $\tan x = 1$ which implies x = $\pi\over 4$. The other case was when $\cos x = -\sin x$. Here, x = $3\pi\over 4$. I don't understand how to proceed from here.

Comment: $3\pi/4$ is not a solution; you need $\cos x$ to be positive.

Comment: If possible, can you give me the full solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We will solve $\sin^{2}(x) = \cos^{2}(x)$, which is obtained upon squaring the equation (so we do not have to deal with sign issues).

$$\sin^{2}(x) = \cos^{2}(x)$$

$$\cos^{2}(x) -\sin^{2}(x) = 0$$

$$\cos(2x) = 0$$

$$x = \frac{\pi}{4} + \pi n, \frac{3\pi}{4} + \pi n$$

$$x = \frac{\pi}{4} + 2\pi n, \frac{5\pi}{4} + 2\pi n, \frac{3\pi}{4} + 2\pi n, \frac{7\pi}{4} + 2\pi n$$

Here, we split into cases of $2\pi n$ periodicity to take advantage of the properties of $\sin$ and $\cos$.

Checking these solutions in the original equation $\vert \sin(x)\vert = \cos (x)$, we find that only $\frac{\pi}{4} + 2\pi n$ and $\frac{7\pi}{4} + 2\pi n$ work. $\frac{7\pi}{4} + 2\pi n$ is equivalent to $-\frac{\pi}{4} + 2\pi n$, so the answer is $\boxed{(\text{B})\ \pm\frac{\pi}{4} + 2\pi n.}$

You can do a sanity check by drawing a quick graph and seeing if the functions intersect in the general region of the conjectured solution.

Answer (score 1):

$$\cos x=|\sin x|\ge0$$

If $\sin x<0, \cos x=-\sin x\iff\tan x=-1$

As $x$ will lie in the $4$th quadrant, $ x=2n\pi-\dfrac\pi4$

What if $\sin x\ge0?$

Comment: Why is it $2n\pi$ ? Shouldnt it be $\pi$ ?

Comment: @HarshDarji, As $\sin x<0,\cos x\ge0, x$ will lie in the $3$rd quadrant

Answer (score 1):

Using Weierstrass [substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution#The_substitution) with $t=\tan\dfrac x2,$

$$1-t^2=2|t|$$

For real $t, t^2=|t|^2$  $$\implies |t|^2-2|t|-1=0$$

$$\implies|t|=1\pm\sqrt2$$

As $|t|\ge0, |t|=\sqrt2+1=\csc\dfrac\pi4+\cot\dfrac\pi4=\cdots=\cot\dfrac\pi8=\tan\left(\dfrac\pi2-\dfrac\pi8\right)$

$$\iff\tan^2\dfrac x2=\tan^2\left(\dfrac\pi2-\dfrac\pi8\right)$$

$$\implies\dfrac x2=n\pi\pm\left(\dfrac\pi2-\dfrac\pi8\right)$$

Comment: (+1) This is a really nice way of utilizing a Weierstraß substitution!

Comment: The answer doesn't match though.

Answer (score 0):

$\cos x$ is positive in the first and fourth quadrant and in these, $|\tan x|$ is $1$ for $x=\pm\dfrac\pi4$. Add $2n\pi$.

Comment: $\tan x=-1$ is a possibility, too.  General solution is $x=\pm\pi/4+2n\pi$

Comment: @Raffaele: ooops, true.

Comment: Ok. so ur adding $2\pi$ since its nπ+π/4 and nπ-π/4. So you're just adding the two equations, correct?

Comment: @HarshDarji: not at all. I am adding $2n\pi$ because of the $2\pi$ periodicity.